# Verification of correct setup of the matrix form of the linear regression problem

Tags: statistics, solution-verification, proof-explanation, least-squares, linear-regression

The following is a question from *Rice's Mathematical Statistics - Ch. 14 - Q-5*

[image]

I wanted to know if the following approach would be the right set up of the problem:

I looked at this as a question of attempting to solve for the true of value of the points $p_{1}, p_{2}, p_{3}$.

To do this we have to first specify the linear model we are going to use. I specified it in the following way:

$$p_{i} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}y_{i,1} + \beta_{2}y_{i,2} + \beta_{3}y_{i,3} + e_{i}$$

Which if translated to matrix form would be:

$$\textbf{P} = \textbf{X} \textbf{$\mathbb{\beta}$}\ \text{where,} \\ 
\textbf{P} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
p_{1} \\
p_{2} \\
p_{3} \\
\end{bmatrix}, \  
\textbf{X} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & y_{1,1} & y_{1,2} & y_{1,3} \\
1 & y_{2,1} & y_{2,2} & y_{2,3} \\
1 & y_{3,1} & y_{3,2} & y_{3,3} \\
\end{bmatrix}, \ 
\textbf{$\mathbb{\beta}$} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\beta_{0} \\
\beta_{1} \\
\beta_{2} \\
\beta_{3} \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\\
\text{where,} \ 
y_{i,j} = 
\begin{cases}
|p_{i} - p_{j}| & \text{if}\ i\neq j \\
|p_{i} - 0| & \text{if}\ i = j \\
\end{cases}  $$

Which would put me in a position to be able to express the least squares expression:

$$S(\textbf{P}) = \sum_{i = 1}^{3} (p_{i} - \beta_{0} - \beta_{1}y_{i,1} - \beta_{2}y_{i,2} - \beta_{3}y_{i,3})^{2} \\
= ||\textbf{P} -\textbf{X} \textbf{$\mathbb{\beta}$}||^{2} \\
= ||\textbf{P} - \hat{\textbf{P}}||^{2}$$

So my concerns:

1. I looked at the question as regressing the $p_{i}$ on to the $y_{i}$, now the way they expressed things in the question it kind of feels as if they wanted me to do the opposite. I may be overthinking it here, but considering this is a first approach at linear regression I don't think they would deviate too much from how they use the $Y_{i}$ variable in the text.
2. I introduced an intercept term $\beta_{0}$, for me I was looking at it as perhaps the distance from the origin to the first point. That was my thinking behind it, but then I also have $\beta_{1}$ which is being estimated based off of distances that use the observed $p_{1}$ value. So would an intercept term be needed here?
3. How is the setup in terms of the overall idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your setup is correct, but maybe it's not what you were asked to do. The question is about using the least-squares method to estimate (directly) the values of $p_i$ given the noisy measurements $Y_i$. If we wanted to state this question as a regression problem, we would be asked to regress $p_i$ given the values of $Y_i$.

The least-squares method is more general than regression and tries to find optimal parameters to some model given data. In our case:

1. We have latent values $p_1, p_2, p_3$ and we have information about $d_{12} = p_2 - p_1, ~ d_{13} = p_3 - p_1, ~ d_{23} = p_3 - p_2$.
2. We have noisy measurements of those quantities given by $Y_1, ..., Y_6$.

We now have to model our problem. The most common way to do it is to consider all measurements to have *iid* errors coming from a normal distribution, i.e. $Y_i = x_i + \varepsilon_i$ where $x_i$ is some data and $\varepsilon_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ are *iid* samples from a gaussian, modeling noise (it can be justified by assuming all the measurements taken independently by the same person / instrument). In our model, we are taking measurements of $p_i$'s and $d_{ij}$'s with some noise, so we can state that each $Y_i$ comes from a gaussian centered in the true values of our quantities of interest.This gives us:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&Y_1 = p_1 + \varepsilon_1; ~~ Y_2 = p_2 + \varepsilon_2; ~~ Y_3 = p_3 + \varepsilon_3 \\
&Y_4 = d_{12} + \varepsilon_4; ~~ Y_5 = d_{13} + \varepsilon_5;~~ Y_6 = d_{23} + \varepsilon_6 \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Where $\varepsilon_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ are *iid* random variables. Our problem looks like a linear regression given only by intercepts. When we deal with *iid* gaussians, the least-squares solution is equivalent to maximum likelihood estimation (MLE). To see it, let's write out our likelihood:

$$
P(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,Y_4,Y_5,Y_6 | p_1,p_2,p_3) = \prod_{i=1}^{6} P(Y_i)
$$

We'd like to maximize that quantity by finding the optimal values of $p_i$'s, i.e. finding the most probable positions which explain our data. Observe that maximizing $\mathcal{L}(p_1, p_2, p_3) := P(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,Y_4,Y_5,Y_6 | p_1,p_2,p_3)$ is the same as maximizing $\log \mathcal{L}(p_1, p_2, p_3)$, for what we have:

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\max_{p_1, p_2 , p_3} \log \mathcal{L}(p_1, p_2 , p_3) \\
& = \max_{p_1, p_2 , p_3}  -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} \left ( \sum_{i = 1}^{6}
 (Y_i - p_i)^2 \right) \\
& = \min_{p_1, p_2 , p_3} \sum_{i = 1}^{6} (Y_i - p_i)^2
\end{aligned}
$$
Where $p_4 = d_{12}$, $p_5 = d_{13}$ and $p_6 = d_{23}$. The last expression is precisely the least squares solution. We were asked to find it's matrix form, for that let's define $T$ by:

$$
T = \left [
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 1 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 1  \\
-1 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}
\right ]
$$

Then, for $Y = [Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,Y_4,Y_5,Y_6]^T$ and $\mathbf{p} = [p_1, p_2, p_3]^{T}$ we finally have:

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\max_{p_1, p_2 , p_3} \log \mathcal{L}(p_1, p_2 , p_3) \\
& = \min_{p_1, p_2 , p_3} \sum_{i = 1}^{6} (Y_i - p_i)^2 \\ 
&= \| Y - T\mathbf{p} \|^2
\end{aligned}
$$
I hope it helps :)

Comment: Two questions: 1) I'm trying to figure out the form of one instance of your defined likelihood function, i.e a $P(Y_{i})$. So going off of what I know and what you mentioned the errors, $\epsilon_{i}$ are normally distributed, which means my $Y_{i}$ should be normally distributed. So that should mean $P(Y_{i}) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} \exp{\left(\frac{-(Y_{i} - 0)^{2}}{2 \sigma^{2}}\right)}$. But I know I'm missing something because further down you have the expression $\sum_{i = 1}^{6}(Y_i - p_i)^2$. Does that mean it shouldn't be $P(Y_{i})$, but instead $P(\epsilon_{i})$?

Comment: and 2) How did you form the matrix $T$?

Comment: Hi! by $P(Y_i)$ I actually mean $P(Y_i \mid p_1, p_2, p_3)$, observe that by our model $Y_i \sim N(p_i, \sigma)$ where $p_4 = d_{12}$, $p_5 = d_{13}$ and $p_6 = d_{23}$. So knowing the values of $p_1,p_2,p_3$ we can determine the density for each $Y_i$. E.g. $P(Y_1 | p_1 , p_2, p_3) = P(Y_1 | p_1) =  \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} \exp{\left(\frac{-(Y_{1} - p_1)^{2}}{2 \sigma^{2}}\right)}$ or in the case of $Y_6$ we'll have $P(Y_6 | p_1 , p_2, p_3) = P(Y_6 | p_2, p_3) =  \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} \exp{\left(\frac{-(Y_{1} - d_{23})^{2}}{2 \sigma^{2}}\right)}$.

Comment: It's easy to construct $T$. Just try to express $\sum_{i = 1}^{6} (Y_i - p_i)^2$ in terms of $\mathbf{p} = [p_1, p_2, p_3]^T$ and $Y = [Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,Y_4,Y_5,Y_6 ]^T$. For example, for $i=1$, the first component of the vector $Y - T\mathbf{p}$, i.e.  $[Y - T\mathbf{p}]_1 = Y_1 - p_1$, in this case, the row we are looking for is just $T[1,:] = [1,0,0]$ (because $Y_1 - T[1,:] \mathbf{p} = Y_1 - p_1$). For $i=6$ we want to recover $[Y - T\mathbf{p}]_6 = Y_6 - (p_3- p_2)$ so we need a row $T[6,:]$ such that $T[6,:] \mathbf{p} = p_3 - p_2$, i.e. $T[6,:] = [0,-1,1]$.

Comment: I see my issue....I don't understand why $Y_{i} \sim N(p_{i},\sigma^{2})$. So the $\epsilon_{i} \sim N(0,\sigma^{2})$ so the $Y_{i}$ are normally approximated, but why is the mean of these $p_{i}$?

Comment: A follow up to constructing $T$. I do understand what you've done now that you explained it. I think my issue is that I expected something to just "fall out" after expressing the $\sum_{i=1}^{6}(Y_{i} - p_{i})^{2}$. In this scenario we could construct this manually, but I could envision this being an issue if we had a huge data set. How would we address that problem?

Comment: $Y_{i} \sim N(p_{i},\sigma^{2})$ because for any random variable $X \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ ($\varepsilon$ in our case) and $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ a scalar ($p_i$ in our model), we have that $Z = X + \mu \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. This is justified by the fact that we are measuring around $p_i$ with some randomness which spreads according to $\sigma$. With respect to the other question, this exercise is intended to learn how the least-squares method works as a general tool (rather than just for regression) so it doesn't have to be that efficient.

Comment: Normally for statistical learning problems, one tackles performance (namely huge datasets) by redefining the model (e.g., using sparse models). As I hope you could see, least squares is a special case of MLE, which is only one way (among many: MAP, Variational Inference, regularization, ...) of optimizing model parameters. The problem of big models is a research area by itself, and sadly I can't give you any general receipt for the least-squares method to perform well in any dataset :(